# For which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ does there exist a specific kind of polynomial that maps $x$ between $-1$ and $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the smallest set of polynomials containing $-1$ and $1$ such that for each $P,Q\in\mathcal{P}$ we have $XP+(1-X)Q\in\mathcal{P}$. Determine the set $S$ of all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which there exists $P\in\mathcal{P}$ such that $P(x)\in(-1,1)$?

It is quite easy to prove that any integer will always be mapped to an odd integer, which gives $S\cap\mathbb{Z}=\emptyset$.

Since $2X-1\in\mathcal{P}$ we find that $(0,1)\subset S$.
Since $-2X^2+4X-1\in\mathcal{P}$ we find that $(1,2)\subset S$.
Since $2X^2-1\in\mathcal{P}$ we find that $(-1,0)\subset S$.

By experimentation and intuition, I suspect that $S=(-\phi,1+\phi)\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ with $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\approx1.618$ the golden ratio. I have some idea as to how to prove the right inclusion, but I have absolutely no idea how to prove the left inclusion.

Comment: What is $X$? Is that really $x$?

Comment: $X$ is the identity polynomial. In this context, you can think of it as just being $x$.

Comment: your suspicious is definitely wrong, since the problem is invariant to $x \mapsto -x$.

Comment: I think the problem is not invariant to $x\mapsto-x$, but to $x\mapsto1-x$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft yea, sorry. I think the left inclusion will follow after you prove a very strong statement about $\mathcal{P}$ by induction. One just needs to find that statement...

Comment: I'm doing some computations, and it seems that if you change definition of $S$ to have $P(x) \in [-1,1]$ instead of $P(x) \in (-1,1)$, then $S$ will conjecturally be $[-\phi,1+\phi]$ instead of $(-\phi,1+\phi)\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. Am I wrong about this? I'm asking because, if I'm not wrong, then the $P(x) \in [-1,1]$ question is cleaner imo.

Comment: I would personally expect that $P(x)\in[-1,1]$ would still give $(-\phi,1+\phi)$, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I now know why I could never prove $S = (-\phi,1+\phi)\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. It's false.

That $2X-1,-1 \in \mathcal{P}$ implies $X(2X-1)+(1-X)(-1) = 2X^2-1 \in \mathcal{P}$. Therefore, since $1-2X \in \mathcal{P}$, we have $H(X) := X(2X^2-1)+(1-X)(1-2X) = 2X^3+2X^2-4X+1 \in \mathcal{P}$. But $H(-2.01) \approx 0.88$.

By code, $S$ includes $x = 10.0441$.

Below are what I think all the polynomials of degree at most $3$ in $S$. All of the integers $-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ get mapped to $1$ by some polynomial below.

$-1,1,1-2 x,-1+2 x,-1+6 x-6 x^2,-1+4 x-4 x^2,1-2 x^2,-1+2 x-2 x^2,-1+4 x-2 x^2,-1+2 x^2,1-4 x+2 x^2,1-2 x+2 x^2,1-4 x+4 x^2,1-6 x+6 x^2,1-6 x+12 x^2-8 x^3,-1+6 x^2-6 x^3,1-4 x+8 x^2-6 x^3,1-6 x+10 x^2-6 x^3,1-6 x+12 x^2-6 x^3,-1+2 x+2 x^2-4 x^3,-1+4 x^2-4 x^3,1-2 x+4 x^2-4 x^3,-1+6 x^2-4 x^3,1-4 x+6 x^2-4 x^3,1-6 x+8 x^2-4 x^3,1-4 x+8 x^2-4 x^3,1-6 x+10 x^2-4 x^3,1-2 x^3,-1+2 x-2 x^3,-1+4 x-2 x^2-2 x^3,-1+2 x^2-2 x^3,1-2 x+2 x^2-2 x^3,-1+2 x+2 x^2-2 x^3,-1+4 x^2-2 x^3,1-4 x+4 x^2-2 x^3,1-2 x+4 x^2-2 x^3,1-6 x+6 x^2-2 x^3,1-4 x+6 x^2-2 x^3,1-6 x+8 x^2-2 x^3,-1+2 x^3,1-2 x+2 x^3,-1+6 x-8 x^2+2 x^3,-1+4 x-6 x^2+2 x^3,-1+6 x-6 x^2+2 x^3,1-4 x^2+2 x^3,-1+2 x-4 x^2+2 x^3,-1+4 x-4 x^2+2 x^3,1-2 x^2+2 x^3,1-2 x-2 x^2+2 x^3,-1+2 x-2 x^2+2 x^3,1-4 x+2 x^2+2 x^3,-1+6 x-10 x^2+4 x^3,-1+4 x-8 x^2+4 x^3,-1+6 x-8 x^2+4 x^3,1-6 x^2+4 x^3,-1+4 x-6 x^2+4 x^3,1-4 x^2+4 x^3,-1+2 x-4 x^2+4 x^3,1-2 x-2 x^2+4 x^3,-1+6 x-12 x^2+6 x^3,-1+6 x-10 x^2+6 x^3,-1+4 x-8 x^2+6 x^3,1-6 x^2+6 x^3,-1+6 x-12 x^2+8 x^3$

Comment: Interesting, do you think $S$ could just be $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft I have no idea. Do you still care? Does this problem come from somewhere interesting..

Comment: @SmileyCraft I mean, I liked the problem cause I thought there would have been something cool going on if the roots were restricted to $[-\phi,1+\phi]$. But otherwise, there's probably no structure and nothing special going on...

Comment: Right, unfortunately I can't remember how I came up with this problem or why I thought $S$ would equal $(-\phi,1+\phi)$.

Comment: It's still pretty interesting though :P I've been messing around with it just now due to your answer. Since any $P\in\mathcal{P}$ maps all integers to odd integers, it would be interesting to know which integers can be mapped to $1$ by some $P\neq1$. If the derivative is non-zero this would show $\mathbb{Z}\subset\overline{S}$. But it would be interesting to find a non-integer number not in $S$. Also, I managed to reason that $\mathcal{P}$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: I think I remember some of the context. You can turn the problem around intuitively: Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and start with drawing the points $-1,1$. Then you can take any two drawn points $P,Q$ and add point $P+x(Q-P)=xQ+(1-x)P$. The goal is to draw a point between $-1$ and $1$. For example let $x=-2.01$. Draw $-5.02$ from $P=-1$ and $Q=1$. Draw $5.02$ from $P=1$ and $Q=-1$. Draw $7.0802$ from $P=-1$ and $Q=-5.02$. Finally draw $0.878998$ from $P=5.02$ and $Q=7.0802$. I think this context makes it interesting.

Comment: I think the reason I expected $S$ to equal $(-\phi,1+\phi)$ was the following strategy. Draw $P_0$ from $-1$ and $1$. For $i\geq1$ draw $Q_i$ from $P_{i-1}$ and $1$ and draw $P_i$ from $Q_i$ and $-1$. For example let $x=2.1$. Draw $P_0=3.2$ from $-1$ and $1$. Draw $Q_1=-1.42$ from $P_0=3.2$ and $1$. Finally draw $P_1=-0.538$ from $Q_1=-1.42$ and $-1$. Now consider $x=1+\phi$. You will find $P_i=2\phi+1$ and $Q_i=-2\phi-1$ for all $i$. However, if $x$ was even slightly smaller, the sequences would get smaller over time and eventually get between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft To make sure i understand, when $x=-2.01$, we have $xQ+(1-x)P = -2.01Q+3.01P$. Can't you just take $Q=P=1$ to get $1.01$ and then $Q=1.01,P=1$ to get $0.9799$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft See updated answer. A direct way to see $x=2$ can nontrivially yield $1$, note $x=2$ gives $2Q-P$; taking $Q=-1,P=1$ gives $-3$, and then $Q=1,P=-3$ gives $1$.

Comment: When $x=-2.01$ and $Q=P=1$ you get $xQ+(1-x)P=-2.01+3.01=1$,so not $1.01$. And when $x=2$, $Q=1$ and $P=-3$ you get $xQ+(1-x)P=2\cdot1+(-1)\cdot(-3)=5$, so not $1$. By the way, the reason it is interesting to study the goal to draw a point between $-1$ and $1$, is that implies the set of points you can draw is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, while otherwise the set would be discrete.

Comment: @SmileyCraft LOL. I always make the funniest/dumbest mistakes around you. Thanks for explaining the motivation; I find the question interesting now as well! I'm currently on a plane, but will think more about the question soon.

Comment: I made some progress on this with a friend yesterday, and we proved $S$ contains all transcendental numbers. Vaguely speaking, we found a superexponential number of different polynomials of each degree, while the evaluations are bounded only exponentially, forcing them to get arbitrarily close together. However we also experimentally figured out that $1+\phi$ is in fact not an element of $S$, although we could not quite prove it yet. We also proved the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is discrete. I am not sure when I have the time to write down everything we came up with.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Thanks for the update!! Will let you know if I have any.